# Retrieved date from a SharePoint list is 4 hours into the future

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Weird bug,

When inserting a SharePoint list item I set the date submitted to DateTime.Now and it is working fine as when I check SharePoint I see the item inserted just fine with the correct date and all values.

```
oListItem["Date_x0020_Submitted"] = DateTime.Now;
```

But when I go to retrieve the exact same list item for some reason the date comes back as 4 hours into the future!!

```
    query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Date_x0020_Submitted' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
    SP.ListItemCollection issuesCollection = oList.GetItems(query);
    MyContext.Load(issuesCollection, (items => items.Include(item => item["ID"], item => item["Date_x0020_Submitted"])));
```

Just to reiterate, after inserting the item I can see it in the list with the correct exact date inserted, but when I retrieve it for some reason it is 4 hours into the future. For example in SharePoint it shows me 10:53, but when I retrieve it shows 2:53.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? It happens for every single item that I insert and retrieve.

Comment: what does the `Kind` property of these 2 values say?

Comment: The date is a "Date and Time" property according to the sharepoint list settings.. but once again in SharePoint the date shows up with the correct date in the list. it's only when retrieving that it changes... Is SharePoint somehow changing the date when retrieving?

Comment: Could there be an issue with the actual time set on the server or your pc.. or maybe the timezone?

Comment: I know nothing about sharepoint, but the value you store to the list (DateTime.Now) has `Kind` equal to `Local`. The value you retrieve from SP is also of DateTime type I guess, right? If so, what does its `Kind` property say, `local` or `UTC`. `UTC` would make sense, depending on your time zone

Comment: My VM says (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada) while the SharePoint Server is (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)... not sure how that could make a 4 hour difference

Comment: Zdeslav where can I check the "Kind" property?

Comment: Yes, but does SP return local time, or the time converted to UTC?
`Kind` is a property of DateTome object, e.g. `DateTime.Now.Kind`

Comment: Sadly it seems that the item retrieved is a simple string and not an actual DateTime object. Converting it to a DateTime simply gives me unspecified for the King property

Comment: What is the exact string content?

Comment: [1] = {[Date_x0020_Submitted, 9/14/2012 3:38:04 PM]}

Comment: this doesn't look like a string. It looks like some pair of data containing the ID and time. What do you get when you call:
`item["Date_x0020_Submitted"].GetType()`

Comment: Yup you were right, it is returned as UTC.

DateTime x = Convert.ToDateTime((DateTime)item[0]["Date_x0020_Submitted"]) did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time which you store is your local time (UTC-5:00, probably with DST). 
Is there any chance that the time returned by Sharepoint is returned as UTC time? `Kind` property of `DateTime` class tells what kind of time it is (this has changed through different versions of .NET framework):

```
var kind = DateTime.Now.Kind;
```

You can convert the returned time to local time and see if it matches:

```
var localTime = utcTime.ToLocalTime();
```

As you say that your time is given as a string (although I suspect that as that format doesn't look like string), you can try to parse it:

```
  string fmt = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"; // this is equivalent to format you have shown
  string stime = "9/14/2012 3:38:04 PM"; // your string here
  var time = DateTime.ParseExact(time, fmt, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  var local = time.ToLocalTime(); // => 14.9.2012. 17:38:04 in my timezone
```

Comment: It was actually being returned as a DateTime as I put in the above comment. Thank you for clarifying what is happening! Now should I be making any changes to the way I insert it or am I fine because the date looks good in the SharePoint server list?

Comment: I find it weird how the date in the bottom right of the windows taskbar shows the exact same date on both machines and the dates in sharepoint are the same as my VM.. The timezone is UTC there but GMT on my machine... and when retrieving the date from there it changes to 4 hours in the future from both times.. but maybe I just don't know enough about dates.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you with Sharepoint as I don't use it. Regarding the different values, I would expect that your machines show local time which is normal for GUI. Sharepoint, however, seems to return UTC time. This make sense as clients might be geographically distributed. This way, they all know what the given time means, while with local time it would not be clear (DateTime class doesn't carry timezone with it), or they would have to convert  it all the time between to locales.
Glad I could help